# Анимация сжатия и расжатия мяча на js

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, анимация, физика, формулы

Есть мяч и 3 поверхности(бетон, дерево, ткань), мы задаем силу с которой он полетит вниз. Нужны формулы для расчета сжатия и расжатия мяча. Одно из главных это расчет радиуса дуги с которой мяч будет сжиматься при различных силах удара.

Comment: "задаем силу с которой он ударится" - стесняюсь спросить, в каких единицах измерения?

Comment: я неправильно сформулировал, мы задаем силу с которой он полетит вниз

Comment: так, может это, открыть учебник по физике?

Comment: я искал, но ничего подходящего к сожалению не нашел, из-за этого я обратился за помощью

Comment: почитайте про деформацию изгиба. https://www.belstu.by/book_library/15655/fizika.-laboratornyi-praktikum.-ch.-1-mexanika-i-molekulyarnaya-fizika-klenickii-d.-v.-kruk-n.-n.-narkevich-i.-i.-tulev-v.-v..pdf
страница 24

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос не имеет полноценного ответа т.к. поставлен в очень широком смысле.
В кратце: вам нужен учебник по физике, постараюсь объяснить почему.

Например

```js
//Описание мира
let World = {
  gravity: 1, //Кооф. гравитации в мире, которая влияет на скорость
  //Также например можно добавить другие факторы в мире
  //Например ветер, который может влиять на векторную скорость шара
  wind: {
    x: 1,
    y: 1
  }
};

//Описание шара
let Ball = {
  //Вес шара
  weight: 1,
  ragius: 10, //Радиус шара
  //Векторная скорость шара
  speed: {
    x: 1,
    y: 1
  },
  //Упругость мячика 
  elasticity: 1.5, //обычно это какой-то кофф. на который домножается скорость при коллизии объекта с другими
  friction: 1.5 //кооф. трения шарика - может понадобится при расчете движения шара по поверхности
};

//Опишу например дерево
let Tree = {
  elasticity: 1.5 //для минимальных простых расчетов будет достаточно значения упругости дерева.
}
```

Итого у вас есть шар, который двигается в неком мире, по нужным вам формулам движения (можно имитировать воду, вакум, космос и т.п.)
Вот на основе веса шара, гравитации, упругости, векторной скорости а также других вводных данных вы сможете начать только рассчитывать необходимые вам показатели. Пока не соберете такую вводную информацию о задаче, ничего рассчитывать вы не сможете, по этому никто вам тут готовой формулы на ваш вопрос не даст. А если вам нужно еще и максимально близко к реальности провести данные расчеты, понадобится еще и сопромат с данными о свойствах материалов и коофицентах. Возможно вам стоит взглянуть в сторону готовых физических движков типа box2d